# newEmbeddedDatabase api needs a path on file system. why cant it use in-memory?

Tags: neo4j, node-neo4j

My need is to use neo4j embedded in my java appliation . As I do not want to store anything on file system, I want to create my database in-memory.
Is it possible in neo4j when it is embedded in my java application?

Comment: just to be clear, you want to lose your data when your application shuts down, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your graph db on a mountpoint using [tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) and disable file buffer caches (use_memory_mapped_buffers=false).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ImpermanentGraphDatabase](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-kernel/1.5.M01/xref-test/org/neo4j/test/ImpermanentGraphDatabase.html) if you want a temporary per request graph model. Or you can try [TinkerGraph's](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/TinkerGraph) in-memory capabilities and use Gremlin for querying/